# Net force on an uncharged conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors

I would like to ask a conceptual question. Consider an uncharged conductor suspended in mid air, is there an electric field that I can introduce to move the conductor,i.e cause a net force on the conductor. I already know that the electrons will move around to the net E-field inside the conductor zero. But would there be a net force, or will the forces on the individual charged particle cancel out. Please give an example if a net force is caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. Consider for example a conducting sphere of radius $R$ with its center at the origin, and a charge $q$ placed on the x-axis at $x=d>R$. It's a well known result that after the electrostatic condition has been reached, we can use the method of image charges and conclude that the final configuration of the fields outside the sphere are equivalent to those of a pair of charges: one $q'=-\frac{R}{d}q$ placed at $x=d'=\frac{R^2}{d}$ and another $-q'$ placed at the origin. From that we can conclude that the electric field at $x=d$ is $$\overrightarrow{E}=\left(-\frac{kq'}{d^2}+\frac{kq'}{(d-d')^2}\right)\hat{x}=kq\left(\frac{R}{d^3}-\frac{Rd}{(d^2-R^2)^2}\right)\hat{x},$$ and therefore the charge feels a force $$\overrightarrow{F}=q\overrightarrow{E}=kq^2\left(\frac{R}{d^3}-\frac{Rd}{(d^2-R^2)^2}\right)\hat{x}.$$
But we know from Newtons Third Law that there must be a reaction force $-\overrightarrow{F}$ acting on the conducting sphere, which is exactly what was to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

If the conductor is not fixed in space, The external electric field E will induce charges on the surface of the sphere. The charges negative charges will be attracted and the positive charges repelled. Thus, the conductor will move towards the source of the E field. Cancellation of the external field occur inside the 'metal' of the conductor. The surface charges do feel a force, which will cause the sphere to move as described.

Comment: There won't be a net force on the sphere or any shaped uncharged conductor.

Comment: WHy not? The induced charges will be attracted.

Comment: I stand corrected. There could be a net force if the external field is non uniform in the sphere.

Comment: I dont understand your claim.  The electric field will cause separation of positive and negative centres, irrespective of the uniformity of the field.

Comment: Please see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90556/does-a-conductor-of-total-charge-zero-placed-in-a-uniform-external-electric-fiel?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

An electrical conductor creates a region in space that is devoid of internal
electric fields.  An electric field contains stored energy, with the density of that energy proportional to the square of the field.  So, the electric field
loses stored energy (does mechanical work) on any conductor that moves
from a low-E-field region to a high-E-field region.

Conductive particles are attracted to the highest field strength
region, and the force on the particles is proportional to the gradient
of the square of the field absolute value.   Nonconductive particles
which have a positive dielectric constant are
also weakly attracted to high electric fields.

As for an example, one need only rub a plastic rod on wool, and see that
it attracts a bit of aluminum foil...